# Chat RSS feed for tagged/xxx not working

Tags: bug, search, chat

When you [search for something in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tagged%2Fcv-pls&room=41570), you can use a phrase like `tagged/xxx` to find all posts with a particular `[tag:xxx]`.

However, the search page's footer contains a [link to an RSS feed of the results](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/feeds/search/tagged%2fcv-pls). This link *generally* works, but not in this case:

[image: Page not found (404) Star Trek edition[1]]

This would be a useful feature to support for programmatic access to chat search. Could it please be fixed?

Comment: A cross between *[Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek)* and *[Firefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_(TV_series))* ([episode 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_(Firefly)#Synopsis))?

Comment: Related (even cross-site self-duplicate?): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385019/chat-rss-feed-for-tagged-xxx-broken